# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filterText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I passed `filterText=this.state.filterText` to the Child Table to filter only the films which contain the letters which I've typed into searcher.

Inside `Table` component I've created function `CheckIfFiltered` to filter the films and to check if the table contains the "filterText".

The problem is that when I try to run it there is an Error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filterText' of undefined"

Although I've passed `filterText` to a props, to the Table component. Please help me solve this problem.

```js
var Row = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.episode.title}</td>
                <td><a href ="top">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});


var Table = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var CheckIfFiltered=function (episode, index, ar){   
            if (episode.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        var filter_rows = this.props.episodes.filter(CheckIfFiltered).map(function(episode){
            return <Row episode={episode} key={episode.title} /> ;
        });

        return(
            <div className="row spacer">
                <div className="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tbody>{filter_rows}</tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var Search = React.createClass({

    changeFilteringSearch: function(){
        this.props.changeFiltering(
            this.refs.filterTextInput.value
        );
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="row ">
                <div className="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <input type="search" className="form-control" value = {this.props.filterText} ref="filterTextInput" onChange={this.changeFilteringSearch} className="form-control" placeholder="Search for episode" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var FilterableEpisodesTable = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            filterText: 'qwerty'
        };
    },

    changeFiltering: function(text){
        this.setState({
            filterText: text
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            episodes=this.props.episodes,
            <div>
                <Search filterText={this.state.filterText} changeFiltering={this.changeFiltering}/>
                <hr/>
                <Table episodes={episodes} filterText={this.state.filterText}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var episodes = [{title : "Angular with Yeoman",},
                {title : "Using D3 with Rickshaw and Angular",},
                {title : "Canvas with paper.js",},
                {title : "Express.js middleware",},
                {title : "Metro",}
                ];

ReactDOM.render(
    <FilterableEpisodesTable episodes = {episodes}/>,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`CheckIfFiltered` runs in a different context as you’ve passed it to filter, so it just needs to be bound.

Either

```
var CheckIfFiltered=function( episode ){            
  if (episode.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}.bind( this )
```

or

```
var filter_rows = this.props.episodes.filter(CheckIfFiltered.bind( this )).map( ... )
```

should help you scope it correctly. Alternatively add it as a class method, I think `React.createClass` autobinds functions but note that if you change to ES2015 syntax the JS native behaviour of never autobinding will take place so you'll have to bind it yourself.

```
React.createClass({
  CheckIfFiltered: function( episode, index, ar ){          
    return episode.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ? true : false
  },
  render: function() { ... }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Now I have to remember about this bind() method and to watch some examples with using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple scope problem, check this and let me know if it helps.

```
render: function(){
        var self = this;
        var CheckIfFiltered=function (episode, index, ar){          
                if (episode.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.props.filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
```